# integrar sweetalert a echo de consulta

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert2, echo

Tengo problemas al imprimir mi alerta, si funciona si le agrego un caracter entre echo y `<script>`

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    if ($sql) {
        
        echo '.
        <script>
        Swal.fire({
            icon: "success",
            title: "Your work has been saved",
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 2500
         });
         window.location = "../admin/admin-culture.php";
        </script> ';

    }
```

en la imagen se puede ver el punto que se agrega, sin un caracter no me quiere correr
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo creen que podría solucionarlo?

Comment: No requieres un echo para enviar una sweet alert, mas bien si puedes checar como hacer que te valide la consulta y si esta es correcta, entonces lanzas el sweet alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario agregar el punto solo debes colocar tu código de esta manera

```
echo '<script>
        Swal.fire({
            icon: "success",
            title: "Your work has been saved",
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 2500
         });
         window.location = "../admin/admin-culture.php";
        </script>';
```